# Heroku run rake db:migrate role error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I've just managed to successfully push my app to Heroku. However, when trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get this weird error:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging --trace                                                                                                                                        [ruby-1.9.3-p125@ramen]
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
FATAL:  role "ngbmsmmcogkdfv" is not permitted to log in
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__988607377061129518__prepare__148721129126176046__callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:295:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Anybody know why I could be getting this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer in Heroku docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#fatal-role-role-name

This occurs when you have de-provisioned a hobby tier database but are still trying to connect to it. To resolve:

- If required, provision a new database via heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql
- Use heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ to
  promote it, making it the primary database for your application.